# Django 404 error even though I've created the path and view

Tags: python, django

I'm just beginning to learn Django.
I've created a simple web sub-app called 'flavo' inside of another one called 'djangoTest'
When I run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/flavo`
it correctly displays
`Hello, World!`
then when I run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/flavo/a` it should show
`Hello, a!`
But instead I get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/flavo/a
Using the URLconf defined in testDjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
flavo [name='index0']
flavo a [name='a']
The current path, flavo/a, didn’t match any of these.
```

in testDjango/hello/views.py I have

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index0(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")

def a(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, a!")
```

In testDjango/flavo/url/py I have

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index0, name="index0"),
    path("a", views.a, name="a"),
]
```

The only other file I've changed is , testDjango/testDjango/urls.py"

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('flavo', include("flavo.urls")),
]
```

I'm confused why I can't access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/flavo/a`

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/a???

Comment: @fakeMake unfortunately that does not work but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add '/'.

like this.

```py
# testDjango/testDjango/urls.py
path('flavo/', include("flavo.urls"))
```

Comment: :) @KatieMelosto